# Why border not cover all element

Tags: html, css

I use border properties of css. When i don't add overflow properties it no cover all elements of id contents.

```css
#contents{border-radius: 10px; border: 1px solid red;overflow:hidden;}
```

```html
<div id="contents">
        <aside>
         <nav>
          <ul>
           <a class="btn-danger" href="">Home Page</a>
           <a class="btn-danger" href="">Main Settings</a>
           <a class="btn-danger" href="">Sections</a>
           <a class="btn-danger" href="">Pages</a>
           <a class="btn-danger" href="">Comments</a>
           <a class="btn-danger" href="">Library</a>
          </ul>    
         </nav>
        </aside>
        <section id="page">
         <p>Hello </p>
        </section>
    </div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qlcjl.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gos4Q.png)

Why add overflow element into code can be corrected???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see, you have a floating elements problem, the issue is.

> A CSS clearfix is used to fix issues related to floating child
>   elements within a parent element. Without a clearfix your child
>   elements wont behave as you expect them too. When a HTML element is
>   floated it can appear to sit outside its parent element and that means
>   it wont adjust the parents height accordingly.

So in your case the inner elements are floating elements. Thus the container is not detecting the height properly.

**Why it works when you use `overflow:hidden`?**

> The Overflow Method relies on setting the overflow CSS property on a
>   parent element. If this property is set to auto or hidden on the
>   parent element, the parent will expand to contain the floats,
>   effectively clearing it for succeeding elements.

So this may be the reason why the parent is filling up the space.

To read more on CSS clearfixes [Read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-a-clearfix) and [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/)